# Laravel 4: Stock Auth login won't persist across pages

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

From all the tutorials, I'm supposed to be able to auth a user then jump to any other page, and the login is persisted. This however, does not work.

Custom compiled PHP LAMP stack. App storage is writable.

The only difference from the tutorials is that I'm using email instead of username.
http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/
http://codehappy.daylerees.com/authentication

Sessions work, as I was able to store a var to session and read it out on a different page.

models/User.php (stock)

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
    echo $this->getKey();
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

config/auth.php

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'User',
    'table' => 'users',

    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
    ),
);
```

config/session.php

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'native',
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => array(2, 100),
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
);
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function(){
    return View::make('home');
}));

Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', function () {
    return View::make('login');
}))->before('guest');

Route::post('login', function () {
    $user = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($user, true)) {
    /*
        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('flash_notice', 'You are successfully logged in.');
      */
    } else {
        /*
        // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
        return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('flash_error', 'Your email/password combination was incorrect.')
            ->withInput();
            */
    }

    // This shows the user as logged in
    echo (Auth::check()) ? 'Logged in' : 'Not logged in';
});

// This shows the user as not logged in
Route::get('test', function () {
    echo (Auth::check() == true) ? 'Logged in' : 'Not logged in';
});
```

Table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userId` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(124) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`, `email`, `password`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'ben.test@smitty.com', '$2y$10$591gwvQKSGXihKruH1s.weHNM1DR/xzavW46vUuSBxEF7Jk0zZe1G', 'Ben Dauphinee', '2013-08-03 23:25:01', '2013-08-07 01:32:46'),
(2, 'jim@dandy.com', NULL, 'Jim Dandy', '2013-08-03 23:25:01', NULL);
```

Resulting Auth::user() info

```
User Object
(
    [table:protected] => users
    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => password
        )

    [connection:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [incrementing] => 1
    [timestamps] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 1
            [email] => bookworm51@hotmail.com
            [password] => $2y$10$591gwvQKSGXihKruH1s.weHNM1DR/xzavW46vUuSBxEF7Jk0zZe1G
            [name] => Ben Dauphinee
            [created_at] => 2013-08-03 20:25:01
            [updated_at] => 2013-08-06 22:32:46
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 1
            [email] => bookworm51@hotmail.com
            [password] => $2y$10$591gwvQKSGXihKruH1s.weHNM1DR/xzavW46vUuSBxEF7Jk0zZe1G
            [name] => Ben Dauphinee
            [created_at] => 2013-08-03 20:25:01
            [updated_at] => 2013-08-06 22:32:46
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [exists] => 1
    [softDelete:protected] => 
)
```

Comment: What's your environment? Local dev? On MAMP, WAMP, or a VM of some sort? Is app/storage writable by php? Any proxies or load balancing in place?

Comment: Also have you tried using a filter instead of `Auth::check()`? Or tried testing `Auth::guest()`? What does `Auth::user()` result in?

Comment: @fideloper Custom PHP but LAMP stack, with writable app storage. Tried filters (one of the tutorials I tried used them), but same result (note the ->before('guest')). I even pulled a fresh copy of Laravel and set the same code, with the same result.

Comment: Try changing column "userId" to "id" in your table. Also - remove "echo $this->getKey();" from your user model. Do either of these solve your problem?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Changing to id does solve the problem. If you can detail in an answer below why that is and how it can be changed to userId, or any other pk name than id, you get the bounty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is you have used "userId" as your primary id - but you have not told Laravel.

[Per the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage): *"Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id"*

**Either**

Change `userId` to `id` in your table *(my personal recommendation - it'll make your life easier if your table always has id)*

**or add this to your User.php file:**

```
protected $primaryKey = "userId";
```

Comment: Why is using id instead of userId recommended? That seems kind of subjective. I'm the opposite, I strongly recommend descriptive pk names.

Comment: its personal - but then whenever you are using your models, you can always do $model->id - and you dont need to do $model->modelId - makes your code cleaner in my personal opinion. You already know $model - so why do you need $modelId.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but I wanted to answer your question. I like using the same attribute across several tables, it's easier to see what is related to what. So 'uid' = id for users table. Then when making the posts table, and I need an attribute set to hold the user id, it's also 'uid'. When working on queries that don't use an abstraction layer it is beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

A copy of your `User` Model would be very useful

Can you verify the following on the `User` Model.

1. If the `User` Model implements Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface. Once you implement the above interface 2 methods needs to be defined as below. Though it is not documented on Laravel, the `Auth` driver makes use of this `UserInterface` to validate the credentials. Take a look at http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Auth.UserProviderInterface.html

   public function getAuthPassword()
   {
       return $this->password;
   }

   public function getAuthIdentifier()
   {
       return $this->getKey();
   }
2. Can you verify if the password on the DB is encrypted. There have been instances with many developers that they have a plain password on the password column. `Auth::attempt` automatically hashes the password using `Hash::make()` and then compares it with the value on the `users` table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ars Added model. It's just the stock one from Laravel though.

Answer (score 0):

i have had this issue long before. just change your php version to any version less then version 5.6